# Writing SQL query: slightly complicated

Tags: sql

I have a table with primary key ID and two columns Order and Status. The value for Status could be any of 'A', 'P', 'S', 'O' or 'C'. I need to to find the values of Order for which the status is only 'A' or 'C'. How should I write an SQL query that does that? I know some basic SQL but I am unable to get my results using that.

Sample table:

```
ID  Order   Status

1   1234    A

2   2343    P

3   4351    S

4   8675    C

5   9867    A

6   9867    C

7   1234    A

8   2343    A

Expected result:

1234

8675

9867
```

Comment: @t-clausen.dk not "status in (A, C)", but "status ONLY in (A, C)". It's not very hard, but I couldn't say it's very simple

Comment: Actually the name of the column in the table is not Order...I just changed it for the purpose of the question. I did not realize that everyone will notice my mistake and comment on it!

Comment: @RomanPekar ok, I misread, I do suppose it is a little tricky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select distinct t.[Order]
from Table1 as t
where
    not exists
    (
         select * from
         Table1 as t2 where t2.[Order] = t.[Order] and t2.Status not in ('A', 'C')
    )
```

or

```
select t.[Order]
from Table1 as t
group by t.[Order]
having
    sum(case when [Status] in ('A', 'C') then 1 else 0 end) = count(*)
```

or

```
select distinct t.[Order]
from Table1 as t
where
    t.[Order] not in (select t2.Order from Table1 as t2 where t2.Status not in ('A', 'C'))
```

see [**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36af1/3) example for details

BTW, `Order` is not the best name for column, avoid using keywords as you column names

Answer (score 4):

With many SQL databases, it's fairly simple using `EXCEPT` (in Oracle, `MINUS`)

```
SELECT [Order] FROM Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT [Order] FROM Table1 WHERE Status NOT IN ('A','C')
```

[An SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db7b8/2)

In MySQL (notably not having `MINUS`), you'll have to go for a more classical;

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Order` FROM Table1 WHERE `Order` NOT IN 
    (SELECT `Order` FROM Table1 WHERE `Status` NOT IN ('A','C'))
```

Comment: +1, nice one, it looks elegant, but I would say that it's not generalizing very well, because you have to specify condition twice. Is it possible to remove first one where clause?

Comment: @RomanPekar Yes, realized the first condition was un-necessary when fixing the MySQL query. Thanks :)